# bash_profile syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

I am getting a syntax error in my .bash_profile when I start up the terminal on Yosemite. Everything I have found online suggests there is nothing wrong with my syntax, although i am getting an error in line 4. Here is error, followed by the .bash_profile code. Can anyone see what is wrong? Is this affecting my ability to install rails (I seem to be having some difficulty with write permissions):

The error:

```
-bash: /Users/admin/.bash_profile: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
-bash: /Users/admin/.bash_profile: line 4: `eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi'
```

The .bash_profile code:

```
export PATH=/usr/loca/bin:$PATH
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
if which rbenv > /dev/null
eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)";
fi

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` statement on line 3 does not have a matching `then`. Until `bash` sees a `then`, it doesn't let you use a `fi`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I deleted lines 3 & 4, which solved the problem. Seem like there was redundant code in .bash_profile, probably because I butchered several rails installs? Let me know if that makes sense - if so I would imagine i am likely to run into additional issues when attempting subsequent installs...

Comment: @ThreeGunas889: You should probably delete line 2, as well; `rbenv` will be run by line 5, if it exists. And line 1 should be `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` (not loca)